# css style not working after published

Tags: css, publish

I have two css classes:

1.-highlightedsearchresult  --> to highlight items in table as they are selected

2.-visitedsearchresult      --> to mark items that have already been visited

Both are defined in my Site.css:

```
    .highlightedsearchresult
    {
     border: medium solid #009999 !important;
     background-color: #FFCC66 !important; /* this should overwrite the background color */
    }

   .visitedsearchresult
    {
     /* border: medium solid #FFFFFF !important;#6699CC  #cc99cc  #99CCFF*/
     background-color:  #cc99cc !important; /* this should overwrite the background color */
     }
```

**My problem is that after publishing the web site locally or onto the server, my visitedsearchresult is not being applied** (highlightedsearchresult style is applied OK in published, thus I know it is not a bad reference to my Site.css). **When I run the web site under Visual Studio 2012 in debug mode both css class styles are being applied as expected**.

And here is the code that applies my styles as appropiate:

```
  $('.SearchResultsTable').on('click', 'tr', function () {

        var index = this.rowIndex;
        if (index == 0) {
            return; //this is the header, do nothing
        }

        $(".highlightedsearchresult").each(function () {
            $(this).addClass('visitedsearchresult');  //if item has the highlighted class, add the visited class before we removed the selected class
            //alert("add visited class");
        });

        var state = $(this).hasClass('highlightedsearchresult');
        if (!state) {
            $(this).removeClass("visitedsearchresult"); //remove our visited class, thus the background is set as selected
            $(this).addClass("highlightedsearchresult").siblings().removeClass("highlightedsearchresult");
        }
        else {
            //alert("removing visited class");
            $(this).removeClass("visitedsearchresult"); //remove our visited class, thus the background is set as selected
        }

        var storyUrl = '@Url.Action("StoryDisplay", "DisplayStory")';
        var file = $(this).attr('SearchResultFilename'); //get filename from our custom attribute
        storyUrl += "?filename=" + file;
        $("#divdisplaystory").css("width", "74%");
        $("#divsearchresults").css("width", "25%");
        $("#divdisplaystory").show();
        $('#divdisplaystory').loadWithoutCache(storyUrl);
    });
```

I would appreciate if anyone has any idea as to why this particular style does not work once published. Any help is greatly appreciate it.

**UPDATE**
I have used Fiddler Web Debugger to see what was happening underneath and found that when accesing the publish web site I get a 401: You are not authorized to view this page due to invalid authentication headers. Still I am able to use the web site, and all my other styles are being applied. Futhermore, I am displaying on the screen the user name (@User.Identity.Name) and it is appearing correct Domain\UserName. So weird. The site has Anonymous Authentication disabled, and Windows Authentication Enabled

Many thanks

Comment: More information would be great. Can you show us what server-side code is generating the HTML, what it renders to locally and when published (view source in browser)? How is the css included? (Using a bundle?) What technology are you using? (I'm guessing ASP.NET MVC from the `@Url.Action()`)

Comment: Also, why are you using `!important`?

Comment: Maybe you have problem with cache. Try to force a cache refresh in browser with ctrl-F5.

Comment: Yes, I am using ASP.NET MVC, the css are imported. I have used google dev tools, and I can see the class visited being added and removed as expected in both publish and debug version. I have just now use the fiddler web debuger and when running the publish version I get an error: will update the post

Answer (score 0):

### I'm not sure ,but sometimes ,when i want to select an id or class with java script and using content palace holder in a master page, tag's id or class change to `ContentPlaceHolder_myID` after publish it .please view your source page. (my solution is useful if you worked with ASP.NET)

i say again that all of my expalins is used if you use ASP.NET technique.
if you have a master page and content page in asp.net (http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/aspnet_masterpages.asp)
 , and use an asp.net tag such as Lable ,your element's Id will change after run the project and you see content page's Id on the prefix of element's id.
for example:

```
<%@ Master %>

<html>
<body>
<h1>Standard Header From Masterpage</h1>
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="CPH1" runat="server">
<asp:Label ID="lblTest" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</body>
</html>
```

after run the project you see:

```
 <span id="CPH1_lblTest">Label</span>
```

label tag after compile change to span tag and it's Id change from `lblTest` to `CPH1_lblTest`.(right click on your web page and select view source)
Now you shuld use `CPH1_lblTest` inestead of lblTest in yur javascript.

Comment: I am sorry Hamid. I do not understand your suggestion, could you please clarify?